# how to use two Lists to insert multiple records in Django Model query

Tags: python, django, list, django-models, django-orm

I have three tables:

table1, table2, table3

from table1 i get the data using:

```
table1queryset = table1.objects.filter(token = 123)
```

it gives me 50 records.

from table2  i get the data using:

```
table2queryset = table2.objects.filter(name='andy')
```

it gives me 10 records.

table3 structure is like:

```
mytoken = models.foreignKey(table1)
myname = models.foreignKey(table2)
```

now for every table1 record i want to insert table2 record into table3. like:

```
for eachT1 in table1queryset:
    for eachT2 in table2queryset:
        table3(mytoken=eachT1,myname=eachT2).save()
```

in my case it will insert 50*10 = 500 records.

what is the most efficiant way of using this?
can i assign both queryset to query, something like:

```
table3(mytoken=table1queryset,myname=table2queryset).save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [RelatedManager.add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add)  It is promised that "Using add() with a many-to-many relationship, however, will not call any save() methods, but rather create the relationships using QuerySet.bulk_create()."

If you define ManyToMany field in first model and tell django that this relationship must work through table 3 (like [ManyToManyField.through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)) you can do:

```
t2s = [x.id for x in tq2]

for t1 in tq1:
    tq.add(*t2s)
```

And probably it will be more efficient than creation of separate instances of T3 model.